# I want to send different email with different manage to Customer and Admin as per payment method. [ Magento 1.9 ]

Tags: magento-1.9, email, payment-methods, sales

How can I send **different sales** emails in **Magento 1.9**?

for example:

**Payment method:**
1. PayU 
2. EFT

**Case 1:**
 - Customer place order and paid with PayU. Customer will receive EMAIL TEMPLATE A ( Customer copy ) and Admin will receive EMAIL TEMPLATE B ( as an acknowledgement ).

**Case 2:**
 - Customer place order and paid with EFT. Customer will receive EMAIL TEMPLATE C ( Customer copy ) and Admin will receive EMAIL TEMPLATE D ( as an acknowledgement ).

Thank you.

Comment: Did you look at this protected $_infoBlockType ='payment/custom_method' in payment models